# Laravel 8 multi-authentication using RolesMiddleware

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, authentication

I'm currently working on a Laravel 8 project which has multiple authetication based on role. However, I am new to Laravel and for a start I created a Middleware for each role (isAdminMiddleware, isUserMiddleware, isManagerMiddleware), and a column "role" in Users table, which can have the values 1, 2 or 3 (1 for admin, 2 for user and 3 for manager).

After some time working on the project I noticed it would be better if I just had a single RolesMiddleware, and possibly convert the values on the role column to their respective names (admin, user, manager). How exactly would I implement this?

Because I'm also using Vue on the project, I would like to pass the role name to the componets so I can render it. For that and other reasons I think having a Middleware for each role is going to be messy and difficult.

Should I create another table for the role? Should I try to rename the column role to role_id and add a role column for the names?

If possible I would rather not use an authentication library given that I'm trying to learn the basics first.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not that messy though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First, create the middleware.

```php
class EnsureUserHasRole
{
    // Make sure to write `...$roles` in the 3rd parameter as it is
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
    {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if (Auth::user()->role === $role ) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return abort(401);  // or redirect to login.. whatever..
    }
}
```

Then register the middleware as usual, and you can use it in the `web` routes like this:

```php
Route::middleware(['ensureUserHasRole:guest'])->group(function () {
    // ...
});

// Multiple roles checking is written with comma separation
Route::middleware(['ensureUserHasRole:guest,admin'])->group(function () {
    // ...
});
```